# Failed to load APIs - Error 403 on Azure Mobile Service

Tags: api, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have staging Azure Mobile Service that has suddenly stopped working and started to report errors when called by other apps.

The direct Mobile Service URL is reporting "Error 403 - This web app is stopped." error at https://b8akjsms2-st.azure-mobile.net/ I am also unable to access the api from the Azure portal which throw this message:

> Failed to download zip file for path '/site/repository/service/api/' in Mobile Service 'b8akJSMS2-st' If you contact a support representative please include this correlation identifier: 4ebe635c-bbb7-af06-a71a-532f0467e828, the time of error: 2016-06-10 11:40:36Z, and the error id: ZE6.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see that the service is on the free tier and is over CPU quota limits. These will reset at midnight UTC each day (5pm PST). Please feel free to contact us if you have any questions.